# One dynamic routes for url like "/" and "/[id].tsx"]?

Tags: next.js, url-routing

How I can create one dynamic-routes file which will handle URL like:

```
domain.com/abc/
domain.com/abc/*
```

At the moment I have two files, one file for `domain.com/abc`, and one file for `domain.com/abc/*`, but it is nonsense because these two files are similar (pagination).

Comment: I think this is what you want ? https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes

Comment: Why dont you just use a query?

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: So if i understand your question its the same page but with different data you are trying to render so /mainpage for example has /mainpage/1 /mainpage/2 etc etc?

Comment: yes, 

I want render
/mainpage
/maingpage/1
/mainpage/2

without
/mainpage/1/*
/mainpage/2/*
and nasted levels...

I readed next documentation, and it is not possible?